# Reclassify a raster in order to polygonize python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, numpy, reclassify

I have a GTiff raster with values from 0 to 255 and I want to reclassify 2 values ( 1 and 2) to 1, and the rest set them to NaN, in order to polygonize later and obtain polygons only for the desired value.

Is there a way of doing this?

```
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName( 'GTiff')
file = gdal.Open( 'area.tif')
band = file.GetRasterBand(1)
lista = band.ReadAsArray()
lista[np.where(lista == 2)] = 1
lista[np.where(lista != 1)] = np.NaN
```

This fails due to `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try masking your array as follows:

```
lista = np.where(lista == 1, 1, lista)
lista = np.where(lista != 1, np.NaN, lista)
```

The structure of this function is `np.where(condition, x, y)` where the function yields `x` if the condition is `True` or `y` if it is `False`.

Answer (score 2):

If you read an array from a raster using `band.ReadAsArray`, it appears that the array type is `numpy.uint8` (check yours with `lista.dtype`), and as such can **only** accept integer values. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708807/numpy-integer-nan).

As such, you have three options:

1) Convert your array to a float array:
`listaFloat = lista.astype(float)`

2) Replace unwanted values with invalid integers: `lista[np.where(lista != 1)] = -99999`

3) Mask your values using: `lista[np.where(lista != 1)] = np.ma.masked`

You would have to see what works best when going forward and creating a raster from the numpy array; that depends on the format you'll be using. I assume that the first or second options should solve your problem.